# Folded MPS state with Mid-circuit measurement

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, tensor-networks

Among some documents I found to make a MPS state on quantum circuit, I can make it with stepped arrangement of unitary operators.

```
|0>--U-----M
     |
|0>--U--U--M
        |
|0>-----U--M
```

And also Honeywell or IBM machine support Mid-circuit measurement and qubit reuse, which we can fold this quantum circuit like,

```
|0>--U--M |0>--U--M
     |         |
|0>--U---------U--M
```

How can I think about bond dimension on this quantum circuit?
Do I have to use multiple qubits to make larger number of bond dimension on MPS state?

Comment: Can you explain what U and what M is? Are the two U's connected by a vertical line one big unitary? And what's the point of the folding picture with regard to your question?

Comment: yes thank you. M is measurement and U is a large unitary with one qubit arbitrary rotation and two qubits arbitrary rotations.